# What is the proper order to pair bluetooth devices in android?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am working on pairing  a client bluetooth device to my phone through an application.  Right now I am using the following code in an asynctask to try and create a socket for the remote device.

```
try{
    ba.cancelDiscovery();
    socket= blud.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
    Method m = blud.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new                  
    Class[] {int.class});
    socket = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(blud, 1);
}catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
```

I don't know if I need to be more along the lines of the BluetoothChat example where I have a Connect Thread and an Accept Thread or if asynctasks are sufficient.

This is the UUID string I am using 00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB
The order in which I am operating is I am listening on the server side and once I have attempted to open the socket for the bluetooth Device I try to connect but end up getting a Permission Denied IO Exception

Answer (score 0):

You need to request bluetooth permission and  BLUETOOTH_ADMIN permission in your manifest
as metioned by the Android API [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html)

"Note: Most methods require the BLUETOOTH permission and some also require the BLUETOOTH_ADMIN permission."

Comment: Are you using listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord or listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord on your server side?  One more thing I can think of is that you would need to turn on discovery mode on the server side for some second (around 120 ~300 max).

Comment: Im  using listenusingrfcommwithservicerecord but in the same asynctask as my createrfcommsockettoservicerecord and turning on discovery mode makes sense i will try this thank you jconfus

Answer (score 0):

For bluetooth permissions, add the following in android manifest file -

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
```

To create bonds use this -

```
public boolean createBond(BluetoothDevice btDevice)  
    throws Exception  
    { 
        Class class1 = Class.forName("android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice");
        Method createBondMethod = class1.getMethod("createBond");  
        Boolean returnValue = (Boolean) createBondMethod.invoke(btDevice);  
        return returnValue.booleanValue();  
    }
```

To create socket -

```
private BluetoothSocket createBluetoothSocket(BluetoothDevice device) throws IOException {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 10){
            try {
                final Method  m = device.getClass().getMethod("createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord", new Class[] { UUID.class });
                return (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, my_UUID);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("No Connection Created", "Could not create Insecure RFComm Connection",e);
            }
        }
        return  device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(my_UUID);
    }
```

Also check [Bluetooth Adapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html) from android developer docs.